# Summing conditionally in SQL

Tags: sql, sum, conditional-statements

I have a table with order_id, user_id, timestamp, dollar_spent. Timestamp is when the order happens. I also have another table with promotion_id, user_id, promotion_rate, start_ts, end_ts. The start and end ts are when the promotion is valid for that user. When a user put in an order when there is promotion active for them will get discounted with promotion rate. There could be orders where there is no active promotion or there could be active promotion but no orders.

Questions: in one output table we need the following 
-- For each promotion rate, the total dollar amount of orders received when active
-- One row for each promotion rate (even if there were no orders)
-- One row for no promotion at all

```
order_id user_id    ts  dollar_amount
1           1   2019-01-06  23
2           1   2019-01-19  18
2           2   2019-01-09  12
```

```
promotion_id user_id    promotion_rate     start_ts end_ts
1               1             0.1        2019-01-03 2019-01-08
2               1             0.15       2019-01-28 2019-02-05
3               1             0.05       2019-09-02 2019-09-10
4               2             0.1        2019-01-03 2019-01-08
```

Comment: what version of SQL? Mysql SQL Server?  And what verison?

Comment: What have you tried so far???

Answer (score 0):

You seem to want a `left join` and `group by`:

```
select p.promotion_rate, count(o.user_id) as num_orders
from promotions p left join
     orders o
     on o.user_id = p.user_id and
        o.ts between p.start_ts and p.end_ts
group by p.promotion_rate;
```

Answer (score 0):

I think you want a full outer since you indicated:

you want one row for all sales dollars when no promotion was active 
One row for each rate when a promotion was active and total_dollars

[Example](https://rextester.com/ESNHG42265)

```
with orders (order_id, user_id,    ts,  dollar_amount) as (
SELECT 1,           1,   '2019-01-06',  23 UNION ALL
SELECT 2,           1,   '2019-01-19',  18 UNION ALL
SELECT 2,           2,   '2019-01-09',  12),
Promotions (Promotion_ID, user_ID, Promotion_rate, start_Ts, End_TS) as (
SELECT 1,               1,             0.1,        '2019-01-03', '2019-01-08' UNION ALL
SELECT 2,               1,             0.15,       '2019-01-28', '2019-02-05' UNION ALL
SELECT 3,               1,             0.05,       '2019-09-02', '2019-09-10' UNION ALL
SELECT 4,               2,             0.1,        '2019-01-03', '2019-01-08')

SELECT P.promotion_rate
     , sum(O.Dollar_Amount) as Total_Dollars
FROM Promotions P
FULL OUTER JOIN Orders O
 on O.TS between P.Start_TS and P.End_TS
GROUP BY P.promotion_rate
```

Results:

```
+----+----------------+---------------+
|    | promotion_rate | Total_Dollars |
+----+----------------+---------------+
|  1 | NULL           | 30            |
|  2 | 0,05           | NULL          |
|  3 | 0,10           | 46            |
|  4 | 0,15           | NULL          |
+----+----------------+---------------+
```

Initially I had included promotion ID; but I believe you want the ID's 1,4 to be combined on 1 row.

Since some records may not be linked to a promotion, the rate would be null and in such situations all records would be combined.

Comment: I think in this case you join when O.TS between P.Start_TS and P.End_TS, it doesn't account for cases when there isn't active promotion and there is orders?